# Mockito - Verify all arguments exactly

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

How can I verify multiple calls to a method with different parameters, and also verify that no other parameters were given?

I know I can test for multiple arguments like this:

```
@Spy
SomeClass someClass

@Test
public void test() {
  someClass.triggerSomething();

  verify(someClass, times(1)).someMethod(1, 1);
  verify(someClass, times(1)).someMethod(2, 2);
  verify(someClass, times(1)).someMethod(3, 3);
  verify(someClass, times(1)).someMethod(4, 4);
  verify(someClass, times(1)).someMethod(5, 5);
}
```

How do I verify that I haven't called it with any other combination of parameters?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't already do this? I ran a test with the same setup as yours and it fails when my arguments differ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`verifyNoMoreInteractions(someClass)`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verifyNoMoreInteractions-java.lang.Object...-).

> Checks if any of given mocks has any unverified interaction.
>
> You can use this method after you verified your mocks - to make sure that nothing else was invoked on your mocks.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: A pity that this will also fail if you invoke SomeClass#anotherMethod